# React Native Flatlist renders the same item multiple times when the data updates

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-flatlist

The react native flatlist component renders the same item as many times as the data list when the data updates. this is for a chat application. when the user clicks the send button, this.state.messages gets updated and causes the flatlist to rerender. however, when it rerenders, all the components are rendered the same.

**Chat.js**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { ChatBubble, Input } from './';

import { Header } from '../header';

class Chat extends Component {
  state={
    messages: [],
  };

  componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({
      messages: [
        {
          text: this.props.navigation.state.params.chat.lastMessage,
          direction: 'left',
          timeStamp: new Date().getTime(),
          id: '666',
          user: {
            displayName: this.props.navigation.state.params.chat.displayName,
          },
        }, {
          text: 'Thanks Nick!',
          timeStamp: new Date().getTime(),
          direction: 'right',
          id: '589',
          user: {
            displayName: 'You',
          },
        },
      ],
    });
  }

  onSend = (message) => {
    const messageData = {
      text: message,
      timeStamp: new Date().getTime(),
      direction: 'right',
      id: Math.random(1000).toString(),
      user: {
        displayName: 'You',
      },
    };
    if (message !== '') {
      this.setState({
        messages: this.state.messages.concat([messageData]),
      });
    }
    setTimeout(() => this.list.scrollToEnd(), 200);
  }

  renderMessages = ({ item }) => {
    return <ChatBubble message={item} />;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'white' }}>
        <Header title={this.props.navigation.state.params.chat.displayName} />
        <FlatList
          keyboardShouldPersistTaps='always'
          data={this.state.messages}
          contentContainerStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'white', justifyContent: 'flex-end', flexGrow: 1 }}
          keyExtractor={message => message.id}
          renderItem={this.renderMessages}
          ref={(ref) => { this.list = ref; }}
        />
        <Input onPress={this.onSend} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  let user;
  if (state.user.user) {
    user = state.user.user;
  }
  return { user };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Chat);
```

**ChatBubble.js**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Clipboard, Text, TouchableWithoutFeedback } from 'react-native';
import moment from 'moment';

import { colors } from '../../config';

let message;

class ChatBubble extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
     message = this.props.message;
   }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles[message.direction].container}>
        <View style={styles.topContainerStyle}>
          <Text style={styles[message.direction].infoStyle}>
            {message.user.displayName}
          </Text>
          <Text style={styles[message.direction].infoStyle}>
            {moment(message.timeStamp).format('LT')}
          </Text>
        </View>
        <Text style={styles[message.direction].message}>
          {message.text}
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = {
  left: {
    container: {
      borderRadius: 20,
      borderBottomLeftRadius: 0,
      marginTop: 8,
      marginRight: 150,
      marginLeft: 10,
      paddingHorizontal: 10,
      paddingVertical: 5,
      alignSelf: 'flex-start',
      backgroundColor: colors.other.chatBubble,
    },
    message: {
      color: 'black',
      padding: 10,
      paddingTop: 5,
      fontFamily: 'avenir_roman',
      fontSize: 16,
    },
    infoStyle: {
      color: 'black',
      padding: 10,
      paddingBottom: 0,
      fontSize: 12,
      fontFamily: 'avenir_light',
    },
  },
  right: {
    container: {
      borderRadius: 20,
      borderBottomRightRadius: 0,
      marginTop: 8,
      marginRight: 10,
      marginLeft: 150,
      paddingHorizontal: 10,
      paddingVertical: 5,
      alignSelf: 'flex-end',
      backgroundColor: colors.secondary.blue,
    },
    message: {
      color: 'white',
      padding: 10,
      paddingTop: 5,
      fontFamily: 'avenir_roman',
      fontSize: 16,
    },
    infoStyle: {
      color: 'white',
      padding: 10,
      paddingBottom: 0,
      fontSize: 12,
      fontFamily: 'avenir_light',
    },
  },
  topContainerStyle: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
  },
};

export { ChatBubble };
```

[image: The behaviour i should get]

[image: The behaviour i currently receive]

Comment: If your array that you provided as props `data` consists repeated data then flatlist renders same. So provide appropriate data.

Comment: I am providing the appropriate data to flatlist. It is only rendering the last index of the array.

Comment: just print your `this.state.messages`. You can see only your last message as part of array.

Comment: Is `ChatBubble` a custom component? Can you please share the code of `ChatBubble` if it is a custom component. BTW try with `key` attribute in `ChatBubble` once.

Comment: I added the ChatBubble custom component code above as well. Since flatlist has a key extractor, there is no need to pass the key as a prop to ChatBubble

Answer (score 0):

From the code you mentioned in the question, it seems the problem is the state not holding previous array element while appending new.

```
const messages = [...this.state.messages,messageData] //
```

considering `this.state.messages` as array holding `supposed data` and same with `messageData` as single element of array.

```
this.setState({ messages:messages  });
```

Comment: when i console.log(this.state.messages), i get the appropriate data. I believe the fix that you have provided is equivalent of concatenating message data into state. I think the flatlist is only rendering the last index of this.state.messages

Comment: Yes, both are same. no flat list render the whole array that you provided.

Comment: is there any other reason why only the last index could be rendering?

Comment: can you make project on https://snack.expo.io try by commenting ref, keyextractor and scroll to end event. just render flatlist